# Why subclass doesn't work in framework, but extension does in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, frameworks

I've created a custom framework in Swift 3, with extensions (for String, UIColors, etc.) and subclass of UITableView and UIView.

Problem is that, when I try to use my subclasses in another project, it doesn't work and crash. And extensions's functions work perfectly...
Subclass doesn't appear in the list of "available classes" in the storyboard. (My class is not in the list of Custom Class, and Module section is empty)

In my framework, my subclasses are public. I also tried with open, and I had the same problem.

Hope it's clear enough and that anyone can help me :)

Edit:
To reproduce the problem:

- Create a Custom class that inherits from UIView like that:

  ```
  public class CustomView: UIView {
      public var name: String = "MyName"
      public func sayMyName() { print("\(self.name)") }
  }
  ```
- Create your framework
- Create a new project, and import your framework.
- Try to instantiate a CustomView in the storyboard.

Comment: you can't see a class from a framework unless you `import` it in a Swift file, that's why your storyboard can't see them

Comment: So I can't use a subclass with only a `.framework`, and need to have my `.framework` and my `CustomView.swift`?
It's weird, why can i have my subclasses in a `.a` in Objective-c, and not a subclass in Swift with a `.framework` ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure your Framework target is accessible to your App project. Two options:

- Add the Framework .xcodeproj file to the project to allow editing either target as you wish. Be aware, only one Xcode project can use it at a time.
- Add the Framework .framework file to the project then make sure it is included in the app's Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

Now that you've added it to your Xcode's app project, you need to do this:

- If you want to access your `open` classes in code, use the syntax:

  ```
  import [framework]
  ```
- If you wish to access your UIKit subclasses in a Storyboard, add their superclass control, then go to Identity Inspector and (1) select your framework as the `Module` and your subclass as the `Class`.

Comment: I made all that things. But in Storyboard, there isn't my framework in the `Module` section, and neither my  class in the `Class` section

Comment: Have you tried changing the *accessibility* of your class? Try changing `public` to `open`? Also, is your subclass IBDesignable (and IBInspectable if needed)?

Comment: Yes but same issue, same problem...
Solve the problem bypassing the subclass with extensions and protocols.. Not very beautiful, but it works haha